# iOS Multiple Picker Views "Parse issue: Expected Expression"

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have multiple pickerviews in 1 view control. It works fine with 2 picker views but when I add any more it comes up with 7 "Expected Expression" errors in the following code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)
        return [categoryTypes count];
    else    
        return [locationTypes count];
    else
        return [originatorTypes count];
    else
        return [destinationTypes count];
    else
        return [statusTypes count];

}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)       
        return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];

}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG) {
        NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

    }else {

        NSString *locationType  = [locationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [locationTypeBtn setTitle:locationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else {

        NSString *originatorType  = [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [originatorTypeBtn setTitle:originatorType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else {

        NSString *destinationType  = [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [destinationTypeBtn setTitle:destinationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else {

        NSString *statusType  = [statusTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [statusTypeBtn setTitle:statusType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

All 7 errors are showing on the separate `else` lines.

Hopefully it's something simple that i'm missing out!!

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

I have all the picker views working now. However the only the only information that changes is the final button rather than each button depending on what is picked.

Here is the complete .m file:

```
#define kPICKERCOLUMN 1
#define kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG 20
#define kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG 21
#define kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG 22
#define kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG 23
#define kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG 24

@implementation HomeViewController

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
        categoryTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Appetizers",@"Breakfast",@"Dessert",@"Drinks",
                         @"Main Dish/Entree", @"Salad", @"Side Dish", @"Soup", @"Snack", 
                         @"Baby Food", @"Pet Food",nil];  

        locationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                         @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                         @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                         @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                         @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                         @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                         @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                         @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                         @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                         @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];

        originatorTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                         @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                         @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                         @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                         @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                         @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                         @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                         @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                         @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                         @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];


        destinationTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                         @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                         @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                         @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                         @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                         @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                         @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                         @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                         @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                         @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];


        statusTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"African",@"American",@"Armenian",@"Barbecue",
                         @"Brazilian", @"British", @"Cajun", @"Central American", @"Chicken",
                         @"Chinese", @"Cuban",
                         @"Ethiopian", @"French", @"Greek", @"German", @"Hamburgers",
                         @"Homestyle Cooking", @"Indian", @"Irish", @"Italian", @"Jamaican",
                         @"Japanese", @"Korean", @"Mexican", @"Middle Eastern", @"Pakistani",
                         @"Pancakes /Waffles", @"Persian", @"Pizza", @"Polynesian", @"Russian",
                         @"Sandwiches", @"Seafood", @"Scandinavian", @"Spanish", @"Soul Food",
                         @"South American", @"Steak", @"Vegetarian", @"Tex-Mex", @"Thai",
                         @"Vietnamese",@"Wild Game",nil];

    }
    return self;
}



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    categoryTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    categoryTypePicker.tag = kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG;
    categoryTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    categoryTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    categoryTypePicker.delegate = self;
    categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    locationTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    locationTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    locationTypePicker.tag = kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG;
    locationTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    locationTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    locationTypePicker.delegate = self;
    originatorTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    originatorTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    originatorTypePicker.tag = kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG;
    originatorTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    originatorTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    originatorTypePicker.delegate = self;
    destinationTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    destinationTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    destinationTypePicker.tag = kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG;
    destinationTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    destinationTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    destinationTypePicker.delegate = self;
    statusTypePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,400,160)];
    statusTypePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    statusTypePicker.tag = kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG;
    statusTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    statusTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    statusTypePicker.delegate = self;
}


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)eve
{

    if ( !locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ( !statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = YES;
    }

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark picker methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return kPICKERCOLUMN;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [categoryTypes count];;
            break;
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [locationTypes count];
            break;
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [originatorTypes count];
            break;
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [destinationTypes count];
            break;
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [statusTypes count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (pickerView.tag) {
        case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [locationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG:
            return [statusTypes objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG) {
        NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kLOCATIONTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *locationType  = [locationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [locationTypeBtn setTitle:locationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kORIGINATORTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *originatorType  = [originatorTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [originatorTypeBtn setTitle:originatorType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kDESTINATIONTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *destinationType  = [destinationTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [destinationTypeBtn setTitle:destinationType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else if (pickerView.tag == kSTATUSTYPEPICKERTAG) {

        NSString *statusType  = [statusTypes objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [statusTypeBtn setTitle:statusType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
-(IBAction) showLocationTypePicker{
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];  
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }



}
-(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker{ 
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

    -(IBAction) showOriginatorTypePicker{
        if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
            locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
        }
        else {
            locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
            categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
        }
        else {
            categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
            destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
        }
        else {
            destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
            statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
        }
        else {
            statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
            [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

-(IBAction) showDestinationTypePicker{
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( statusTypePicker.hidden) {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:statusTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        statusTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [statusTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }

}

-(IBAction) showStatusTypePicker{
    if ( locationTypePicker.hidden) {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:locationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        locationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [locationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( originatorTypePicker.hidden) {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:originatorTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        originatorTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [originatorTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( destinationTypePicker.hidden) {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:destinationTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        destinationTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [destinationTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ( categoryTypePicker.hidden) {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
    }
    else {
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;
        [categoryTypePicker removeFromSuperview];
    }






}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [locationTypes release];
    [categoryTypes release];
    [originatorTypes release];
    [destinationTypes release];
    [statusTypes release];
    [categoryTypePicker release];
    [locationTypePicker release];
    [originatorTypePicker release];
    [destinationTypePicker release];
    [statusTypePicker release];;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: if(somthing){ somthing }else{ anything }else{ of what? }

Comment: do you really have lot's of picker views with different tags, or should you be switching on a single picker view's selectedRow?

Comment: @danh I have multiple picker views with different tags. The idea is that it populates an email when sent and a different picker view will populate a different line in the email.

Comment: okay, do you have the other problem fixed?  not sure I understand it.  it might warrant it's own question.  maybe start by walking through in the debugger, see if it branches the way you expect.

Comment: Yeah the other problem is all sorted now. I think i'll start a new question. Thanks for your help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax problem is straight forward: those else's need conditions, like:

```
if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)
    return [categoryTypes count];
else if (pickerView.tag == kSOMEOTHERTAG_THAT_MEANS_USE_LOCATION_TYPES)
    return [locationTypes count];
else if (// etc.
```

An `if` can have a single `else` with no condition.  The implication is that the else condition is the complement of the if, i.e....

```
if (someCondition) {
    // some statements
} else {  // this implies: else if (!someCondition) 
    // some statements
}
```

But any more than one becomes ambiguous.  A `switch` statement would be an even better choice...

```
switch (pickerView.tag) {
    case kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG:
        return categoryTypes count];
        break;
    case kSOMEOTHERTAG_THAT_MEANS_USE_LOCATION_TYPES:
        return [locationTypes count];
    // etc 
    default:
        break;
}
```

But I'm wondering if the logic makes sense, switching on picker view's tag.  You would do this to distinguish between many picker views -- is that what you mean?  Maybe the conditional branching should be done on what's been picked (selectedRow) in a single picker view?

Comment: Thank You very much!! The issue i'm having now is that no matter what picker view I chose it will only change the final selection.